# having trouble to get the NPT working

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, lammps

I am currently encountering challenges in successfully conducting NPT simulations in LAMMPS for a triclinic cell persistently remain unchanged throughout the NPT simulation.my input file is:

```
# Units and boundary conditions
units           lj
boundary        s s s

# Atom style
atom_style      atomic

# Pair potential
pair_style      lj/cut
pair_coeff      1 1 1.0 1.0

# Initial velocity
velocity        all create 1.0 87287

# Time step
timestep        0.005

# NVT settings
fix             mynvt all nvt temp 1.0 1.0 10.0

# Dump settings
dump            mydmp all custom 1 dump.lammpstrj id type xs ys zs vx vy vz

# Thermodynamic output
thermo_style    custom step time temp etotal press
thermo          1
thermo_modify   format 4 %20.15g
thermo_modify   format 8 %20.15g
thermo_modify   format 9 %20.15g
thermo_modify   format 10 %20.15g
thermo_modify   format 11 %20.15g

# Run the simulation
run             1000
```

Comment: Did you edit your question?

Comment: @Dalmarus can you please explain what happened here? I have read pretty much every question and every answer and every comment and every edit/revision on this site and have never seen the need for redacting information like this, and I have never see "removing proprietary information" in an edit description in my more-than-a-decade frequenting many sites on the network. I searched Meta.SE to find out why you might have done that, and the best that I found was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/391772), which doesn't seem to be what you did.

Comment: @NikeDattani The Community Support team received a ticket and acted upon it. Due to the nature of the ticket, I won't discuss exact details. Whenever I use "removing proprietary information" it typically refers to company URLs.

Comment: I see that the [OP wrote a flag](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userid=8698) 2 hours before Dalmarus edited the post.

Comment: the question has become bogus because there's not even an attempt to do NPT dynamics in the input deck provided

Answer (score 3):

The `aniso` keyword requests anisotropic pressure control, meaning that only **box lengths** are controlled independently:

> The keyword aniso means x, y, and z dimensions are controlled
> independently using the Pxx, Pyy, and Pzz components of the stress
> tensor as the driving forces, and the specified scalar external
> pressure.

(from the [LAMMPS manual](https://docs.lammps.org/fix_nh.html))

If you want to change the **box angles** as well, you'll have to use `tri`, allowing for a triclinic box:

```
fix             mynpt all npt temp 100.0 100.0 $(100.0*dt) tri 1 1 $(1000*dt)
```